# MATLAB function handles and parameters

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, function-handle

When I type `help gmres` in MATLAB I get the following example:

```
n = 21; A = gallery('wilk',n);  b = sum(A,2);
tol = 1e-12;  maxit = 15;
x1 = gmres(@(x)afun(x,n),b,10,tol,maxit,@(x)mfun(x,n));
```

where the two functions are:

```
function y = afun(x,n)
    y = [0; x(1:n-1)] + [((n-1)/2:-1:0)'; (1:(n-1)/2)'].*x+[x(2:n); 0];
end
```

and

```
function y = mfun(r,n)
    y = r ./ [((n-1)/2:-1:1)'; 1; (1:(n-1)/2)'];
end
```

I tested it and it works great. My question is in both those functions what is the value for `x` since we never give it one?

Also shouldn't the call to `gmres` be written like this: (`y` in the @handle)

```
x1 = gmres(@(y)afun(x,n),b,10,tol,maxit,@(y)mfun(x,n));
```

Comment: I think this is pretty well explained by the documentation. Specifically, take a look at [function handles](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) and [parametrizing functions](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html).

Comment: I've read all of these. My question isn't answered in them. If you read my question maybe you can answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function handles are one way to [parametrize functions](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html) in MATLAB. From the documentation page, we find the following example:

```
b = 2;
c = 3.5;
cubicpoly = @(x) x^3 + b*x + c;
x = fzero(cubicpoly,0)
```

which results in:

```
x =
   -1.0945
```

So what's happening here? [`fzero`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) is a so-called *function function*, that takes function handles as inputs, and performs operations on them -- in this case, finds the root of the given function. Practically, this means that `fzero` decides which values for the input argument `x` to `cubicpoly` to try in order to find the root. This means the user just provides a function - no need to give the inputs - and `fzero` will query the function with different values for `x` to eventually find the root.

The function you ask about, [`gmres`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gmres.html), operates in a similar manner. What this means is that you merely need to provide a function that takes an appropriate number of input arguments, and `gmres` will take care of calling it with appropriate inputs to produce its output.

Finally, let's consider your suggestion of calling `gmres` as follows:

```
x1 = gmres(@(y)afun(x,n),b,10,tol,maxit,@(y)mfun(x,n));
```

This might work, or then again it might not -- it depends whether you have a variable called `x` in the workspace of the function eventually calling either `afun` or `mfun`. Notice that now the function handles take one input, `y`, but its value is nowhere used in the expression of the function defined. This means it will not have any effect on the output.

Consider the following example to illustrate what happens:

```
f = @(y)2*x+1; % define a function handle
f(1) % error! Undefined function or variable 'x'!

% the following this works, and g will now use x from the workspace
x = 42;
g = @(y)2*x+1; % define a function handle that knows about x
g(1)
g(2)
g(3) % ...but the result will be independent of y as it's not used.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did read this example in the documentation page but saw that fzero finds an appropriate x. I didn't realize gmres worked the same way. So not needing to specify an x has to do with the fact that gmres and fzero work that way? For a function like the one in your example you always have to give a value to x?

Comment: To put it simply, the function handle has its own workspace of variables. Whatever is not input to it (via the input parameter list) has to be known at the time the function handle is created, and comes from the workspace where the handle is defined. So this allows you to do e.g. `y=1; f = @(x)2*x+y` to have a single-input function that uses the input `x`, but also knows what value the constant parameter `y` should have. Of course, the two functions do somewhat different things, the way they use handles is conceptually same - the user doesn't provide the input to them, the function decides it.